# Matching the column names of two pandas data-frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two pandas dataframes with names `df1` and `df2` such that 
`

```
df1: a      b    c    d
     1      2    3    4
     5      6    7    8
```

and

```
df2:      b    c   
          12   13
```

I want the result be like

```
result:    b    c    
           2    3    
           6    7
```

Here it should be noted that  `a  b   c  d` are the column names in pandas dataframe. The shape and values of both pandas dataframe are different. I want to match the column names of `df2` with that of column names of `df1` and select all the rows of `df1` the headers of which are matched with the column names of `df2`.. `df2` is only used to select the specific columns of `df1` maintaining all the rows.  I tried some code given below but that gives me an empty index.

```
df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
```

The above code is not giving me my resut as it gives index headers with no values. I want to write a code in which I can give my two dataframes as input and it compares the columns headers for selection. I don't have to hard code column names.

Comment: It seemed like all you needed was `df1[df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)]`.

Comment: You had the column names, you just needed to index `df1` with it.

Comment: Or, `df1[df1.columns & df2.columns]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df = df1[df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)]
```

Or like @Zero pointed in comments:

```
df = df1[df1.columns & df2.columns]
```

Comment: No concat needed, have a look on the expected result ;-)

Comment: is there a way to do this but for 2 different dataframes of different lengths with differing columns? like maybe df1 has a,b,c,d,e,f and df2 has b,c,g,h,k?

Comment: @BenjaminDiaz - indices are not important, solution should working well with `df1 has a,b,c,d,e,f and df2 has b,c,g,h,k?`

Answer (score 2):

Or, use `reindex`

```
In [594]: df1.reindex(columns=df2.columns)
Out[594]:
   b  c
0  2  3
1  6  7
```

Also as

```
In [595]: df1.reindex(df2.columns, axis=1)
Out[595]:
   b  c
0  2  3
1  6  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to intersection:

```
df = df1[df1.columns.isin(df2.columns)]
```